# Remove single character occurrence from String

Tags: string, algorithm, duplicates

I want an algorithm to remove all occurrences of a given character from a string in O(n) complexity or lower? (It should be INPLACE editing original string only)

eg.

```
String="aadecabaaab";

removeCharacter='a'

Output:"decbb"
```

Comment: "Can we write an algo" Yes.

Comment: In javascript this works: "aadecabaaab".split("a").join("")  You can employ a similar technique in Java.

Comment: I want an algo. Please don't consider this a problem of Java etc. regarding immutable objects.

Comment: @pxm You'd be constructing a new string anyway as shifting a mutable string would be a worst-case of O(n^2) for the entire algo if my estimation is correct. A StringBuilder is just a specialized string that can be modified, though appending would work in any case in O(n)

Comment: Since you *can't mutate a `String` in Java* .. this question is rather silly. The answer is: You can't. If you were talking about arrays ... well, what have you tried? Seems like a `for` loop is `O(n)` to me.

Comment: Sorry for java tag, removed it. Consider it an char array if you want.

Comment: You can consider it anything you'd like. SO isn't a "Give me teh codez" site, especially when it's obviously HS / CS101 homework.

Comment: Ok u're right by the way it was a question in Amazon interview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it in place with a `String` because it's immutable, but here's an O(n) algorithm to do it in place with a `char[]`:

```
char[] chars = "aadecabaaab".toCharArray();
char removeCharacter = 'a';
int next = 0;
for (int cur = 0; cur < chars.length; ++cur) {
    if (chars[cur] != removeCharacter) {
        chars[next++] = chars[cur];
    }
}
// chars[0] through chars[4] will have {d, e, c, b, b} and next will be 5
System.out.println(new String(chars, 0, next));
```

Comment: Is this truly O(n) complexity seeing as .toCharArray() also could be O(n) underneath the covers?  I am curious.

Comment: @RalphCaraveo - Two O(n) operations in sequence is still O(n). Presumably, though, providing the input should not be considered part of the run-time complexity. Calling `toCharArray` was just a simple way to get the individual characters out of the string.

Answer (score 3):

Enjoy algo:

```
j = 0
for i in length(a):
  if a[i] != symbol:
    a[j] = a[i]
    j = j + 1
```

finalize:

```
length(a) = j
```

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, you can't remove anything from a `String` because the `String` class is immutable.  But you can construct another `String` that has all characters from the original `String` except for the "character to remove".

Create a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).  Loop through all characters in the original `String`.  If the current character is not the character to remove, then append it to the `StringBuilder`.  After the loop ends, convert the `StringBuilder` to a `String`.

Comment: I know it, consider it a problem in C/C++ or any other language. Just need an algo

Comment: @pxm You'd be constructing a new string anyway as shifting a mutable string would be a worst-case of `O(n^2)` for the entire operation if my estimation is correct. A StringBuilder is just a specialized string that can be modified, though appending would work in any case in `O(n)`.

Comment: Sure, it can be generalized to any programming language, but you tagged Java, so I gave a Java algorithm.

Comment: A very sorry for that. Removed it.

Comment: This is the algorithm: "Loop through all characters in the original String. If the current character is not the character to remove, then append it to the StringBuilder."

Answer (score 0):

Yep. In a linear time, iterate over String, check using .charAt() if this is a removeCharacter, don't copy it to new String. If no, copy. That's it.

Comment: I don't need new objects.

Comment: String is immutable object, you can't change it once it created.

Comment: This would only work for a mutable object (such as `StringBuilder`). But this is not O(n). Removing a character is an O(n) operation and you are doing it O(n) times.

Comment: Ted, you answer it to me? If yes, my algo is completely O(n), there is no any removing in O(n) complexity

Comment: When you `removeCharacter`, you need to move the trailing characters one position in the underlying character array (to close up the gap from the removed character). That is an O(n) operation since on average there will be n/2 trailing characters. Since the number of characters to be removed is (also on average) proportional to n, the result is an O(n^2) algorithm.

Comment: @TedHopp I think removeCharacter was a variable in the original question, not a method.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I completely misread your answer. On re-reading it, you have an O(n) algorithm. However, it is not an in-place algorithm, which was another one of OP's requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This probably shouldn't have the "java" tag since in Java, a String is immutable and you can't edit it in place.  For a more general case, if you have an array of characters (in any programming language) and you want to modify the array "in place" without creating another array, it's easy enough to do with two indexes.  One goes through every character in the array, and the other starts at the beginning and is incremented only when you see a character that isn't removeCharacter.  Since I assume this is a homework assignment, I'll leave it at that and let you figure out the details.

Answer (score 0):

Use a hash table to hold the data you want to remove. log N complexity.

```
std::string toRemove = "ad";
std::map<char, int> table;
size_t maxR = toRemove.size();  
for (size_t n = 0; n < maxR; ++n)
{
    table[toRemove[n]] = 0;
}
```

Then parse the whole string and remove when you get a hit (thestring is an array):

```
size_t counter = 0; 
while(thestring[counter] != 0)
{       
    std::map<char,int>::iterator iter = table.find(thestring[counter]);
    if (iter == table.end()) // we found a valid character!
    {
        ++counter;
    }
    else
    {
        // move the data - dont increment counter
        memcpy(&thestring[counter], &thestring[counter+1], max-counter);
        // dont increment counter
    }
}
```

EDIT: I hope this is not a technical test or something like that. =S

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class removeA{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    String text = "This is a test string! Wow abcdefg.";
    System.out.println(text.replaceAll("a",""));
  }
}
```